# Which is the best rocket fuel?

Tags: fuel

I searched on internet about rocket fuel and the most common fuel is $\ce{KNO3}$ + sugar (rocket candy), but I think that I could use another fuel methods, like using can with gas or using $\ce{HCl + Al}$.

My question is: Which one ($\ce{KNO3}$ + sugar, can with gas or $\ce{HCl + Al}$) gets more performance? Can I increase the performance by increasing the pressure and the durability?

Comment: Please take the necessary precautions when working with these substances and, when in doubt, please consult with someone that is an expert in this area.

Comment: When i refer to best is to the performance.

Comment: Do you mean rocket fuel for home experiment?

Comment: What do you mean by performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `Zn` + `S` as a teenager. It is a lot safer than Al, and you can mix it cold.

Stick to solid propelants because it's simpler, safer and smaller. You don't want an explosion but something very quick burning.

Mix the two fine powders well.

You can mix them in a thick plastic bag or wide mouth bottle and shake until you see an even color in all the mix with no lumps in sight.

(You can make a paste with alcohol 100% but I never tried this.)

Then tap it in with wood or plastic. You don't want a spark! Nozzle reduction is 1/3 and not smaller. The mix is 3:1. Light with a filament, it is safer than a spark.

In those days all I had was a book but you can find a lot of info out there.

We switched to this after a (not too serious) accident with rocket candy.

Safety first allways, the rocket can go anywhere!

Comment: Why do you say that? Could the Hydrogen released on the reaction `HCL` + `AL` be inflammable?

Comment: I searched about that and Hydrogen is Highly inflammable.

Comment: Stick to solid propelants because it's simpler, safer and smaller. You don't want an explosion but something very quick burning.

Comment: Yeah, to make a solid propelants with Zn + S you mix it cold and stick with a hammer?

Comment: Mix the two fine powders well and tap it in with wood or plastic. You don't want a spark! Nozzle reduction is 1/3 and not smaller. The mix is 3:1. Light with a filament, it is safer than a spark. I'm remembering a lot...

Comment: There are references like [Model rockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_rocket). BE VERY CAREFULL!

Comment: Yeah safety first! I searched about ZnS and it is extremely sensible to hot. When you sai that i can mix it cold, how can i do that?